# Get employee with tenure of 2 to 5 years in sql

Tags: sql

I have a tenure table where I have columns link id, name, join date of an employee.

I am trying to get only those employee whose tenure(work experience) is 2 to 5 years from join date to today's date.

I used query

```
SELECT ID FROM tenure WHERE DATEADD(year, 2, JoinDate) >= '2018-08-06' AND DATEADD(year, 5, JoinDate) <= '2018-08-06';
```

My tabular structure is
[image]

How can I get only those employees whose working period or tenure is between 2 to 5 years from their join date to today's date?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Assuming your RDBMS is MySQL, you just need to replace the '2018-08-06'  with NOW()

Comment: I did that also but the logic with date(month) does not match and I am getting wrong data because the month is ignored with this logic

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TimeStampDiff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) :

```
SELECT ID 
FROM tenure t
WHERE timestampdiff(YEAR, JoinDate, now()) >= 2 AND 
      timestampdiff(YEAR, JoinDate, now()) <= 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function

```
  SELECT ID FROM tenure WHERE
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date(joindate), date(now()))>= 2  and
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date(joindate), date(now()))<=5
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, your syntax suggests SQL Server.  The logic would be:

```
where joindate >= dateadd(year, -5, getdate()) and
      joindate < dateadd(year, -2, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare the Joindate to the expected range based on today's date

```
select *
from tenure 
where joindate between DATE_ADD(cur_date(), INTERVAL -5 YEAR) 
                   and DATE_ADD(cur_date(), INTERVAL -2 YEAR)
```